# Plotting a function on the different axis

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I've solved the DE:

$$a\cdot x(t)+b\cdot\ln\left(1+c\cdot x(t)\right)=-p\cdot x'(t)\tag1$$

Where $x(0)=k$

And I got the following solution:

$$t=\int_{x(t)}^k\frac{p}{a\cdot z+b\cdot\ln\left(1+c\cdot z\right)}\space\text{d}z\tag2$$

If I want to plot the solution in mathematica I get on the y-axis the time $t$ but I want time at the x-axis, how can I solve that?

The code is equal to:

```
Plot[Integrate[(5*10^(-3))/((78/10)*
      z + ((((5463/
              20) + (20))*(((138064852)/(100000000))*10^(-23))*(2))/((\
(16021766208)/(10000000000))*10^(-19)))*Log[1 + ((z)/(10^(-4)))]), {z,
    x, Pi}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Only the axis needs to be swaped.

Comment: try `ParametricPlot`?

Comment: @kglr How can I do that?

Comment: Jan, if you post the code that produced the plot you want changed, it will be easier for all to answer your question.

Comment: @kglr I did what you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[int]
int[x_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(5*10^(-3))/((78/10)*
     z + ((((5463/20) + (20))*(((138064852)/(100000000))*10^(-23))*(2))/
      (((16021766208)/(10000000000))*10^(-19)))* Log[1 + ((z)/(10^(-4)))]), 
  {z,  x, Pi}]

plot = Plot[int[x], {x, 0, 1} , 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

#### ParametricPlot

```
Quiet@ParametricPlot[{int[x], x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
    PlotRange -> Reverse[PlotRange[plot]]]
```

[image]

#### Post-process

Alternatively, you can post-process `plot` to reverse the coordinates of `Line` objects:

```
Show[plot/. Line[x_] :> Line[Reverse /@ x], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]